# Change Ubuntu locale in Docker

Tags: postgresql, locale, docker, ubuntu-14.04

So I'm setting up a docker image with Ubuntu and Postgresql in pt_BR and I'd like to know how can I change the default locale via command line without restarting the system - which is not possible in a Docker build :).
I managed to do it in Debian by changing setting LANG,LANGUAGE and LC_* variables in `/etc/default/locale`, modifying `/etc/locale.gen` and running `dpkg-reconfigure`, as shown [here](https://github.com/gsmiro/docker/blob/master/bucardo/setlocale.sh). In Ubuntu it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It should work with Ubuntu similarly.

A sample Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN  apt-get install -y language-pack-pt-base
ENV  LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
```

Running a container from that image, `ls --help` will be presented in Portuguese.