# Can't configure locale in Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, locale, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

I'm trying to install a locale file in my Docker image, but for some reason it doesn't install correctly.

These lines inside my `Dockerfile` do configure + install the locale files:

```
# Install and configure locales
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "locales"]
RUN ["locale-gen", "nl_NL.UTF-8"]
RUN ["dpkg-reconfigure", "locales"]
RUN ["update-locale"]
ENV LANG nl_NL.UTF-8
```

The image is created succesfully. When I run `docker exec **ID** locale -a` I still get the following error:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

So I guess it didn't installed the locale files correctly. Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702662/2798777

Comment: Can you please show the output of docker build command. And from what I can reckon, you have to write apt-get update first as it is unable to find the packages sometimes. So try that. Try updating apt-get and then install locales.

Answer (score 5):

Try both `locales` and `locales-all`

like :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    locales \
    locales-all \
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit to late but, I hope this helps someone else. Had similar isue and the following comands work for me

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:22.04


# Set the locale
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales \
    locales-all 
RUN locale-gen nl_NL.UTF-8  
ENV LANG nl_NL.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE nl_NL:nl 
ENV LC_ALL nl_NL.UTF-8  
RUN update-locale LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8
```